# How do I define the dataUserFolder of WebView2 Component with Delphi

Tags: delphi, webview2, delphi-10.1-berlin

I want to use `WebView2` with my Delphi program. It works in the IDE (as there the runtime program is in an documents folder) but in my installed program the `userDataFolder` is in `<exe.-Prg-name>.Webview2` as I can read here:  [For non-UWP apps, the default user data ({Executable File Name}.WebView2) folder is created in the same directory next to the compiled code for the app.](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/microsoft-edge/webview2/reference/win32/webview2-idl?view=webview2-1.0.992.28#createcorewebview2environmentwithoptions)

How can I change this userDataFolder, so it has READ/WRITE permissions. In my Program Folder under Windows 10 there are no permissions. I do not want to let the installer of my program install my program under documents, where the prg has READ/Write permissions.

I have no idea where in my `Delphi Berlin` Source I could define this userDataFolder.

Edit: Also the WebView component [for enable EdgeBrowser Feature also to Delphi 10.2 Berlin] from [WinSOFT](https://winsoft.sk/webview.htm) has in its newest version 3.3 the `DataFolder` Property. In Version 3.1 it was still missing.
Thanks for any help.
Walter

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that describes the problem you're having or question you're asking. Your current title is simply a repetition of the information in the tags. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem. Your current title does not provide any useful information - it's simply a regurgitation of the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TEdgeBrowser` has a property `UserDataFolder` that you can change for the purpose. This property exists in the currently latest Delphi version (*Delphi 11 Alexandria*). I don't know when it has been introduced.

Comment: have you any new information about the topic? we tried your approach in the project created with 10.4.2. The user data folder is always created in exe folder.   
    EdgeBrowser1.UserDataFolder := 'C:\temp\BlaBlaBla';
    EdgeBrowser1.ReinitializeWebView;

Comment: No new information. You should upgrade to Delphi 11.